# React-native touch move event across components (something like onMouseEnter)

Tags: react-native

I'm making a custom calendar component with a month view where each day is a specialized component. When the user puts his finger on a day and moves across the screen I want to do something in each touched day component. In other words I need something like `onMouseEnter` event from standard react.

Here's what I've tried:

1. Passing gesture handlers to View inside each day.

I've added `onStartShouldSetResponder`, `onMoveShouldSetResponder`, `onResponderTerminationRequest` (all 3 return true), `onResponderGrant` and `onResponderMove` to a View in my custom day component and that works for a single day, but when the user moves his finger to the next day its handlers are not called until the finger is lifted and put on it again.

2. Creating a `PanResponder` in the calendar component and passing its handlers to all days.

Well this one was a blind try. It wouldn't have much sense if it did work :)
 I've created a `PanResponder` in the parent calendar component and passed `panResponder.panHandlers` to every day. It works the same as method 1.

The method I'm sure would work:

- attach `onLayout` to each day
- store bounding boxes of each day in the state of the calendar component
- attach gesture handlers to the calendar view itself
- in the gesture handlers using current touch coords (x,y) and stored bounding boxes figure out which day is touched

But there's got to be a simpler, elegant method for a more civilized age, right? :)